# mysql "AND" clause on datetime column two times

Tags: mysql, database

i am trying to retrieve a datetime row which 
start > '08:30:00' AND
 start < '18:00:00'
AND
start > '2017-10-01' AND
 start < '2017-11-01'

This is what i've tried:

```
SELECT Entrada , Saida FROM table 
WHERE Saida IS NOT NULL 
  AND TIME(Entrada) BETWEEN '08:30:00' AND '18:00:00'
  AND DATE(Entrada) BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-05-01'
ORDER BY Entrada ASC
```

This returns rows between '2017-04-01' AND '2017-05-01' but not between '08:30:00' AND '18:00:00'.

So how can i handle this situation?

Comment: Why is your query not working? Your question is not clear. Provide sample data and desired result.

Comment: What day of the week was `2017-04-00` this year?

Comment: @fancyPants updated

Comment: `DATE(Entrada)` is a computed value and it cannot use an index. Use `Entrada BETWEEN '2017-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-04-30 23:59:59'` to let MySQL use the index. It helps a lot.

Comment: @axiac that can retrieve for example: 2017-04-01 06:00:00 , that's not the case in here

Comment: You didn't get my point. Read my answer below for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not clear but I assume you want to get the rows having the value of `Entrada` in April 2017, between `8:30` and `18:00`.

The query you posted should work fine but, because of the use of functions (`DATE(Entrada)`, `TIME(Entrada)`) it cannot use an index. It processes the entire table and it will run more slowly as the time passes and the records pile up into the table.

Do you have an index on the `Entrada` column, don't you?

The solution is to replace `DATE(Entrada)` with a condition that compares the value of `Entrada` with a date interval that includes all the daily intervals you want (the whole April 2017, including the night time). Such a condition will use an index on the `Entrada` column to limit the rows it processes further. The second condition (against `TIME(Entrada)`) will process only the records filtered by the first condition, not all the records from the table as it happens now.

The query is

```
SELECT Entrada, Saida
FROM table
WHERE Saida IS NOT NULL
  AND Entrada BETWEEN '2017-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-04-30 23:59:59'
  AND TIME(Entrada) BETWEEN '08:30:00' AND '18:00:00'
ORDER BY Entrada ASC
```

You can use `Entrada BETWEEN '2017-04-01 08:30:00' AND '2017-04-30 18:00:00'` as well.

Comment: yes , the query was working right , ty for the solution replacing DATE(Entrada).

Comment: You can and should omit the time part in the between because you'd miss for example events at `2017-04-30 23:59:59.1000` instead use `Entrada between '2017-04-01' and '2017-04-30'` which is equal to `Entrada >=  '2017-04-01'  and Entrada < '2017-05-01'`. Of course in this case it doesn't matter since these times are not relevant in this sepcific case.

Comment: @JanZeiseweis `Entrada BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-04-30'` means `'2017-04-01 00:00:00' <= Entrada AND Entrada <= '2017-04-30 00:00:00'`. Not quite what the OP asked. Sure, the `DATETIME` on the newer versions of MySQL also includes milliseconds but they are irrelevant for this question.

Comment: You're right, my fault. I thought it automatically includes the entire date. Thanks for clarifying. I'd probably still use the other approach since you can quite easily miss entries if they occurred in the last milliseconds. And have fun debugging if you're suddenly missing 2 rows every day. ;)

Comment: *"If one of the arguments is a `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` column and the other argument is a constant, the constant is converted to a timestamp before the comparison is performed"* -- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html

Answer (score -2):

Try to use `EXTRACT()` function of MYSQL (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions052.htm))

Comment: It's not about the extract, but the select between those dates and times